# Can not set EdgeDriver version using WebDriverManager

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

I have a trouble with running Selenium tests with Edge. Windows is going to update on version 4.15063. But currently this update is not automatic. But latest version for Edge already switched 4.15063. I am using WebDriverManager but without success to work with previous version.

```
EdgeDriverManager.getInstance().version("3.14393")setup();
```

Does not loading previous version of driver. Webdriver manager version is 1.6.2. I have tried to set version for EDGE in few ways with:

```
System.setProperty("wdm.edgeVersion", "3.14393")
```

and like

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
capabilities.setVersion("3.14393");
driver = new EdgeDriver(capabilities);
```

Also without success. But I can check that in debug

```
EdgeDriverManager.getInstance().getDriverVersion()
```

return resultof version according to set from any of methods above.
 Though the same option for ChromeDriverManager works properly and correct version of driver binaries loaded.
I guess that there is some problem in DriverManager.
Using downloaded binaries from local store let me to run EdgeDriver successfully.

Comment: I have made some investigation and see that in BrowserManager.class line 143 - List<URL> urls = this.getDrivers(); versionToDownload becomes "4.15063" which is latest.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WebDriverManager 1.6.2 (and below) does not support the selection of the version of Edge driver. This [issue](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/135) is related.

Fortunately, WebDriverManager 1.7.0 (and above) supports the selection of the version, also for Edge, as follows:

```
EdgeDriverManager.getInstance().version("3.14393").setup();
```